# Compare radio button value to object with one JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I've started coding a quiz in JavaScript in my free time. My current code is up at https://codepen.io/kennycrippen/pen/JZMyPw

My question involves lines 46 to 70 of the JS:

```
// loop through the radio buttons for question 1
var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('radio-0');
for (r = 0; r < radio.length; r++) {
radio[r].addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    if(this.value != allQuestions[0].correctAnswer) {
        alert('Incorrect');
    } else {
        alert('Correct');
    }
});
}

// loop through the radio buttons for question 2
var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('radio-1');
for (r = 0; r < radio.length; r++) {
radio[r].addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    if(this.value != allQuestions[1].correctAnswer) {
        alert('Incorrect');
    } else {
        alert('Correct');
    }
});
}
```

These two loops are doing essentially the same thing. In the interest of keeping my code DRY, what is the best way to combine these loops into one? I've been experimenting all day but am at a bit of a roadblock. Thanks!

Comment: Hints: a loop; `"radio-" + i`; `allQuestions[i]` — that would be the most trivial set of changes to make. Have a look at [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods_of_the_Object_constructor) and [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods, though. In any case, it’d be of interest what exactly you’ve tried. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], along with all the _errors_ you’ve encountered.

Comment: One other option is to add a callback function to your questions array. Then, just develop a general function that takes in the selected and answer and passes in the question object. Within that function, you will always be doing the same thing: checking if the passed in answer matches the passed in question object's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. I have tried to keep your HTML intact, although some changes may make it even more easier. You can use data-attr in place of appending qstn no to Id names.

Hope it helps.

```js
// Quiz Questions Object
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"],
    correctAnswer: 'David Cameron'
  },
  {
    question: "Who is President of the United States?",
    choices: ["Barack Obama", "Ted Cruz", "Donald Trump", "Margaret Thatcher"],
    correctAnswer: 'Donald Trump'
  }
];


// Loop throught the allQuestions object
for (i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
  // get the question and output to the document
  var question = allQuestions[i].question;
  var choices = allQuestions[i].choices;
  var correctAnswer = allQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
  var questionHTML = document.createElement('div');
  questionHTML.innerHTML = question;
  questionHTML.className = 'question-' + i;

  document.getElementById('questions-' + i).appendChild(questionHTML);

  // get the choices and output to the document
  for (j = 0; j < choices.length; j++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'choice';
    div.innerHTML = '<input class="radioclass" type="radio" name="radio" value="' + choices[j] + '" id="' + choices[j].replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '">' + '<label for="' + choices[j].replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '">' + choices[j] + '</label>';

    document.getElementById('questions-' + i).appendChild(div);
  }

  // add the next question button
  var nextButton = document.createElement('button');
  nextButton.innerHTML = 'Next';
  nextButton.className = 'question-' + i + '-next';

  document.getElementById('questions-' + i).appendChild(nextButton);

}

// loop through the radio buttons for question 1
var radio = document.getElementsByClassName('radioclass');
for (r = 0; r < radio.length; r++) {
  radio[r].addEventListener('change', function() {
    var parentQuestionId = this.parentNode.parentNode.id.replace('questions-', '');
    console.log("parentQuestionId:", parentQuestionId);
    console.log(this.value);
    if (this.value != allQuestions[parentQuestionId].correctAnswer) {
      alert('Incorrect');
    } else {
      alert('Correct');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>A Fun JS Quiz Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="questions-0"></div>
  <div id="questions-1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @sns, this works well and the data attribute idea is a great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Put all the similar code in a named function.

```js
function setup_radios(radioClass, correctAnswer) {
  var radio = document.getElementsByClassName(radioClass);
  for (r = 0; r < radio.length; r++) {
    radio[r].addEventListener('change', function() {
      console.log(this.value);
      if (this.value != correctAnswer) {
        alert('Incorrect');
      } else {
        alert('Correct');
      }
    });
  }
}

allQuestions.forEach((q, i) => setup_radios("radio-" + i, q.correctAnswer));
```